# Subgroups of infinite Galois group $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\ldots)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\ldots)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ contains some subgroups which are not equal to the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms fixing an intermediate subfield $K$.

This is a common example mentioned in infinite Galois groups.

**Question:** Is there anything mentioned in literature/book, that, which subgroups could not be realized as the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms fixing an intermediate subfield $K$, and which subgroups can be realized?

Comment: Sorry, misread. How much infinite Galois theory do you know?

Comment: I am in very beginning of it; so this is first example I visited; but the natural question arose, did not found in notes or book

Comment: Ok, have you learned something about profinite groups or the Krull topology? For the record, your question is answered by infinite Galois theory, but I'm not sure how presentable the result is to you.

Comment: I have heard of the result describing bijection between intermediate fields and "some" subgroups, defined topologically. But, question I am considering is about a very particular example, and I want to see which subgroups of its Galois group do not arise in mentioned form.

Comment: $E= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\ldots)$. The subgroups that are of the form $Gal(E/K)$ for some subfield are those of the form $\{ \sigma\in Gal(E/\Bbb{Q}), \forall n\in S, \sigma(\sqrt{n})=\sqrt{n}\}$ with $S$ some set of positive (squarefree) integers. A non-example is $H=\{1,\rho\}$ where $\rho(\sqrt{p})=-\sqrt{p}$ for all prime $p$ (the subfield fixed by $H$ is $\Bbb{Q}$). The key idea is that $Gal(E/K) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in K} Gal(E/\Bbb{Q}(\alpha))$.

Comment: @reuns $\rho$ fixes $\sqrt{pq}$ for $p,q$ distinct primes, so the fixed field is much larger than $\mathbb{Q}$. $H$ is finite, so necessarily closed in the Hausdorff topological group $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$, so it is the Galois group of its fixed field by infinite Galois theory. Explicitly, I think the fixed field is generated by all $\sqrt{pq}$ as above and $E$ has degree $2$ over this by adjoining any one $\sqrt{p}$, $p$ prime.

Comment: Yes sorry this was a nonsense. Really need to take a subgroup $G$ such that $Gal(E/\Bbb{Q})=H\oplus G$